# Need to mock Firebase Auth but unsure how

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I use Firebase to manage authentication within my app. This has a singleton object for the logged in user: `Auth.auth().currentUser`

In part of my code I check that the `uid` of the logged in user is equal to a `userId` associated with an object.

I need to test code that uses this check. For this I need to be able to inject a mock Firebase Auth object.

How can I mock the Firebase Auth object? Has anyone had experience with this before?

Comment: Don't mind me asking - what are you trying to achieve with the mocking?

Comment: @JadGhadry Just updated my question. I need to do unit tests that use the Firebase Auth object

Comment: where you able to setup a testing flow for this?

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiast I was, I just posted my answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I solved this by creating a few protocols for authentication and making `User` conform to that protocol:

```
protocol AuthUser {
    var uid: String {get}
    var displayName: String? {get}
    var email: String? {get}
    var photoURL: URL? {get}
}

extension User : AuthUser {}

protocol AuthenticationProtocol {
    var currentUser: AuthUser? {get}
}
```

Then I created an `Authentication` class that conforms to the `AuthenticationProtocol`:

```
final class Authentication: AuthenticationProtocol {
    static let shared = Authentication()
    private let auth = Auth.auth()
    var currentUser: AuthUser? {
        return auth.currentUser
    }
}
```

When I have a class that needs authentication in my app I inject a class that conforms to `AuthenticationProtocol` like this:

```
final class MyClass {
    private let auth: AuthenticationProtocol

    init(auth: AuthenticationProtocol = Authentication.shared) {
        self.auth = auth
    }
}
```

Then I can get the id of the current logged in user by calling `auth.currentUser?.uid`.

For tests I then create a mock class that conforms to `AuthenticationProtocol` like this:

```
final class AuthenticationMock : AuthenticationProtocol {
    private let uid: String
    let currentUser: AuthUser?

    init(currentUser: AuthUser) {
        self.currentUser = currentUser
    }
}
```

And then I can inject that when I call `MyClass(auth: <Authentication Mock Instance>)`